Adding sink tap into bathroom drain
I just pulled a tub out of my basement bathroom. I'm looking to add a sink to to the outside wall of the bathroom. My question is can I tie the drain into this setup? This run is vented and the tub is the only drain connected to the run. I was thinking I could either add a tee right below the overflow so that is not impacted by this run. The full run of this new drain will be about 3 feet. Also, if I can do this should I trap the drain or can I use this trap? Thanks




No, you cannot add the sink drain into the bathtub above the p-trap (the red portion in my sketch). You need to connect to the bathtub's drain line downstream of the p-trap shown in your photos. The new drain would then offset up into the wall, have a trap arm to pick up the sink and continue with a vent.
It would be helpful to have a better understanding of the other fixtures in this bathroom and the location of the new sink to provide a more detailed answer.


I would remove the trap that would be buried in the floor and put it up under the sink. Much easier to maintain.
I see no real problem using re-using the former tub drain for the sink. In fact many bathrooms that have both sinks and tubs/showers end up having all the drains sharing a common piping system.

I read this question as adding the sink to the replacement bathtub.

Yes. I would like to add a new sink drain to this existing setup. Or possibly modify this setup to accommodate the additional drain for the sink
